# Illegal username in Mac Single User

Tags: macos

My sudoers permissions changed and I am trying to correct that. I get the erro message sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by gid 80, should be 0. When I try to change the ownership to 0 I get the error message: chown: 0.0: illegal user name

Answer (score 4):

[BSD `chown`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/chown.8.html) uses `:` to separate the user and group, not `.`.

```
chown 0:0 sudoers
```